# Delimit string in Python while handling Edge case

Tags: python, sql-server, regex

I have a requirement to parse the Explicit columns of a SQL query into a list in Python.
All works well until I hit a specific scenario.

Given a specific SQL query, I am faced with the below explicit columns:

```
column_a, column_b, column_c, row_number() over (partition by column_a, column_b, column_c order by column_a asc) as agg_column
```

This is returned as a string to Python, where I need a Python list in the below format:

```
parsed_list = ['column_a','column_b','column_c','row_number() over (partition by column_a, column_b, column_c order by column_a asc) as agg_column']
```

However this throws up the obvious issue of delimiting the columns in the Window function like so:

```
table_columns = 'column_a, column_b, column_c, row_number() over (partition by column_a, column_b, column_c order by column_a asc) as agg_column'
print(table_columns.split(','))

Out[1]:
['column_a',
 ' column_b',
 ' column_c',
 ' row_number() over (partition by column_a',
 ' column_b',
 ' column_c order by column_a asc) as agg_column']
```

I am somewhat new to regex, but I am able to identify the SQL Window function in the string with the pattern:

`\w+\((\w+)?\)\sover\s\(.+\)\sas\s\w+$`

However, is it possible to:

1. Split the list as normal with `my_column.split(',')`
2. But also allow for the edge case mentioned above to parse the desired output shown again below

`['column_a','column_b','column_c','row_number() over (partition by column_a, column_b, column_c order by column_a asc) as agg_column']`

Comment: You could use regular expression in split  `print(re.findall('\w+,',table_columns))` or `print(re.findall('\w+,',table_columns))` but given that the sql syntax will vary for complex statements I guess will be hard to form the reg ex for all cases.. this is my thought..

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I was thinking of using an **or** in an if block in python. However, the issue is re.findall('\w+,',table_columns) would need to exclude the columns in the window function for one side of the or, and I'm not sure how I can do this.

Comment: One dirty way to do it would be to get the distinct column names using a set(). `print(set(re.findall('\w+,',table_columns)))`